# How to change one .xib file to another file using .m file in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova

I am working phonegap related project

- **first .xib**  file i have webview
- from java script file it comes to .m file
- .m file i want to navigate **to another .xib file**

any one help me. ..

i want to know possible to navigate one .xib file to another .xib
    is it possible  means the first .xib file in  uiwebview means 
is possible to navigate another .xib file

thank in advance,

Comment: You have to ask more detailed. I dont get it. You just want to navigate from a view to another view and both get loaded from a nib file?!

Comment: yes i want to navigate .m file (means uiviewcontroller to one new .xib file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [[delegate viewController] presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the `window.rootViewController`, or use an `UINavigationController`, or an `UITabbar`? Have a look at the documentation and example projects.

Also you could present the second viewController modally using the first one: `[viewController presentModalViewController: secondViewController animated: YES]` (smth like that..)